# Codeigniter active record query with array

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, codeigniter, activerecord

Im using this query:

`$lang`  is like this `Array ( [0] => Afrikaans [1] => English )`

```
    $this->db->select('id');
    $this->db->from('language');
    $this->db->where_in('language',$lang);
    $query = $this->db->get();
    $l_id =$query->result_array();
```

For this query, when I use `print_r($l_id)` Im getting an output like this:

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( [id] => 1 ) [1] => Array ( [id] => 21 ) )
```

But I need something like this:

```
Array ( [0] =>  1  [1] =>  21 )
```

Someone please help me to do this. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try like this...

```
$this->db->select('id');
$this->db->from('language');
$this->db->where_in('language',$lang);
$query = $this->db->get();
$l_id =$query->result_array();  
foreach($l_id as $key=>$value)
{
   $ids[] = $value['id'];
}
print_r($ids);
```

For example:

```
$l_id = array(array('id'=>'1'),array('id'=>21));
//print_r($l_id);
foreach($l_id as $key=>$value)
{
    $ids[]=$value['id'];
}

print_r($ids);
```

Comment: @Shihas glad to help you..lets cheers and best of luck ahead.

Answer (score 0):

Replace:

```
 $l_id =$query->result_array();
```

With:

```
 $l_id =$query->result();
```

OR try

```
 $l_id =$query->row();
```